# Can Stack Overflow Inc. purchase the .se top-level domain?

Tags: feature-request, domain-names

I was reading the article *[Canon to begin acquisition of the ".canon" Top-Level Domain name](http://www.canon.com/news/2010/mar16e.html)*.

It seems Canon is the first company to spring for ICANN's new policy, allowing corporations and businesses to purchase their own TLD (Top Level Domain).

I began to think... wouldn't this be the **perfect** thing for the Stack Exchange network? Especially considering [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/stack-exchange-naming-for-dummies/)  from [the Stack Overflow blog](http://blog.stackexchange.com). That way, we can have:

- [apple.se](http://apple.se) instead of [apple.stackexchange.com](http://apple.stackexchange.com)
- [webapps.se](http://apple.se) instead of [webapps.stackexchange.com](http://webapps.stackexchange.com)
- ...

This won't be cheap. The fees quoted on [this page](http://www.wired.com/epicenter/2010/03/canon-domain/) are $185,000 US - **but**, I think it would be a worthy investment as more and more sites are launched.

---

I forgot that Sweden owns the TLD `.se`. My idea still stands... perhaps `.exchange` or something.

Comment: *goes off to propose goat-raising site on A51*

Comment: [FWIW...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.se) I suspect the Swedes will want a lot more than $185K to give up their domain.

Comment: I'd keep in mind that $185,000 is for a *brand new* TLD; if you wanted to buy an *existing* TLD you'd probably have to buy out every single existing domain that's on it.

Comment: @Shog9: Okay, but the idea still stands.

Comment: @George: I'd love to see `.exchange`. Especially if we could get traction behind a multiple sclerosis support proposal.

Comment: And the idea of sites being hosted on a ".exchange" or ".questions" TLD just fills me with so much *ick*. It's almost worse than being a stackexchange.com subdomain.

Comment: @Shog: There's no need, we already have [Mindstorm](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4105/lego-mindstorms-robotics).

Comment: @Aaro: excellent...

Comment: @Shog: Someone needs to propose a new A51 site dedicated to the [S](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S_%28programming_language%29) programming language.

Comment: FWIW, Rosinante [had this idea](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55855/website-naming-discussion-should-not-be-public/55983#55983) eons -- well, months -- ago. (Shog, Pekka had yours.)

Comment: @PopsOnDemand: HA!

Comment: So, that probably gets one things like `nl.canon` for their site for The Netherlands? (Hopefully they won't try to use a single "Dutch" site for, among others, The Netherlands and the Dutch/Flemish part of Belgium.) Plain waste of money, if you'd ask me...

Comment: Pick `.sex`, expect lag.

Comment: `unix.exchange` is actually impossible.

Comment: If people want to start saving for the $185k, my paypal account details are.... :P

Comment: @intuited for the sake of asking, why is that impossible?

Comment: (Wondering about jcolebrand's comment too, @intuited.)

Comment: Because they don't have any sex to change.  (cue drum fill)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

*We don't have quite the funding to purchase Sweden, so `.se` is out. Unless… Send your $1 donation to the Purchase Sweden Fund. P.O. Box…*  Wait, no.

Any crazy, custom domain we could come up with would work contrary to users' expectations, and only work to confuse or mislead them.

If you saw an article that said "Go to Ubuntu.questions for your Ubuntu questions", how would you interpret that? Most users would simply stick a .com on the end. The rest… it means *nothing* to them.

I'm not sure I see the upside (maybe a bit of publicity, is all).

Comment: Well, most users don't bother typing in a full domain anymore anyway, thanks to autocomplete... still, I guess it could be slightly confusing.

Comment: @George Edison: I actually looked into this and only after found the non-standard TLD's off-putting. So your suggestion wasn't completely unfounded. Keep 'em coming.

Comment: I think it would have been a better idea if .se would have been available.

Comment: Well, you don't have to _purchase_ Sweden. Just rent it for a while to see how it goes.

Comment: As said, `se.com` exists and from the outside, doesn't seem to be in massive use. Might be worth an enquiry

Answer (score 6):

As others have said, the Swedes pretty much have us locked out.

Now, [the sorta-Dutch and `.sx`, on the other hand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.sx)....

Comment: Nice! So we have to somehow sink Sint Maarten. That sounds more realistic than purchasing Sweden.

Comment: The island's population is roughly the same as the number of active SO users. We could just, y'know, move down there _en masse_. "Stack Exchange: World's best Q&A network slash benevolent banana republic!"

Comment: @Popular interesting idea. The country could introduce a reputation-backed currency, exporting answers to the rest of the world. It would be a member of the EU, with all the perks that come with that. The climate seems to be a-ok as well!

Comment: I call dibs on [Geneve Bay](http://bit.ly/g3OJBv). I'm building my house there

Comment: @Pekka, @PD: are you proposing ... *The SO Commune*? Sounds eerily familiar - replace nicks as appropriate: http://everything2.com/title/A+jaundiced+look+at+Everything2+Kansas

Comment: @Piskvor It would be the first commune with a T3 connection.

Comment: @Pekka: Hmm, it does look habitable; wonder whether the local water sources are sufficient for a population of that size? Good news: there are three different cables on the island (via two landings), so connectivity should be fairly solid.

Answer (score 4):

[image]
<sub>(source: [backpacking.se](https://www.backpacking.se/grfx/MemberPictures/sweden_sucks3.jpg))</sub>

It's always Sweden, isn't it?

Comment: I think you will get many a toast tonight from your finnish user base. What show is that image from? Who is that guy?

Comment: @Pekka: are you joking?

Comment: @Michael nope... But then, except for the Simpsons, My Name Is Earl, and Weeds, I am profoundly unfamiliar with american TV :)

Comment: @Pekka: Blame me and my American viewpoint. Late-night talk-show host of some note in the US. [Sample](http://video.teamcoco.com/video/conan.jsp?oid=245467)

Comment: @Michael ah, of course! I knew the name, but not the face. Nice clip

Comment: I'm tempted to use the freehand circle script on this image... :P

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: Another version of the now-broken image: http://gfx.bloggar.aftonbladet-cdn.se/wp-content/blogs.dir/428/files/2015/02/usa15.jpg

Answer (score 3):

It might be practical and useful to just get some individual domains: `cooking.se`, `english.se`, etc.  It wouldn't make sense to use them as the canonical locations of the sites, because there would be no way of guaranteeing the availability of future area51 graduates.  But they could be set up to forward to the canonical locations in order to correct people who see `english.SE` written somewhere and take that to be a literal URL.

So just using them as sort of a fallback address, when they're available or can be bought at a minimal price, could be worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to have a four letter or more for a TLD. Under 4 letters are reserved.

I'd go for `.stack` or `.questions`.

`apple.questions`
`programming.questions`

Comment: Technical issue: although 4+letter domains have existed for some time, much software assumes TLDs are `[a-z]{2,3}` - my `.name` domain gets rejected as invalid (and I always get all *righteously offended* about it ;)), I'd guess `.stack` would get thrown out right away with many apps. Yes, this is incorrect behavior, but given its prevalence for **standardized** TLDs, I fear the acceptance rate in custom ones.

Comment: @Piskvor well in that case, the TLD needed is `.sex` for Stack Exchange! Nothing easier than that.

Comment: @Pekka: Such proposal has been done to death, even in 2004 (pun not intended): ".sex considered dangerous" http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3675.html

Comment: I hate when people kick my .info domain, like on email addresses. So frustrating.