# How many TLDs are currently owned by Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-exchange

I want to know, how many [top-level domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) (TLDs) are currently owned by Stack Overflow?

As I know there is only **stackoverflow.com**. Are there any other TLDs owned by Stack Overflow?

Comment: The technical answer is none, since `stackoverflow.com` is not a TLD (`.com` is).

Comment: @TimStone Heh, you just beat me to it ...

Comment: Surely, it ownes `.se`?

Comment: I believe se is for Sweden

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals - Never heard of it.

Comment: Oded, see [Confusion with domain names such as Superuser.SE, SU.SE and Sharepoint.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137641)

Comment: @Oded I've been _trying_ [to tell people about `.sx`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81717/131713)....

Comment: @PopularDemand In Italian, that would be a short for _left_, in the same way _dx_ is a short for _right_. `;)`

Comment: Related: [Can we have a list of all the Stack Exchange domains somewhere, for firewall purposes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81379/335251)

Answer (score 8):

stackoverflow.com is owned by Stack Exchange, not by "stackoverflow".

It also owns:

- answerama.com
- apptivate.ms
- arqade.com
- askdifferent.com
- askpatents.com
- askubuntu.com
- basicallymoney.com
- blogoverflow.com
- chiphacker.com
- crossvalidated.com
- hatdash.com
- me3missions.com
- nothingtoinstall.com
- s.tk
- seasonedadvice.com
- skyrimvsmw3.com
- serverfault.com
- sstatic.net
- stackapps.com
- stackauth.com
- stackexchange.com
- superuser.com
- winterba.sh

And probably some more.

Comment: Note: Stack Exchange, Inc. now does business under the name Stack Overflow.

Comment: I've edited a list of Stack Overflow domains in a different answer to include `stackoverflow.co`. Any objections to my editing it into this answer? It's used for the data request URL (https://policies.stackoverflow.co/data-request/)

Answer (score 7):

Stack Exchange don't own any TLDs.

stackoverflow.com is a domain. It's not a TLD; a TLD is a Top-Level Domain, such as .com and .uk

Of the Stack Exchange domains, there is at least these:

- [AndroidFoodFight.com](http://AndroidFoodFight.com)
- [AnswerAma.com](http://AnswerAma.com)
- [AppTivate.ms](http://AppTivate.ms)
- [arqade.com](http://arqade.com)
- [askdifferent.com](http://askdifferent.com)
- [AskPatents.com](http://AskPatents.com)
- [AskSigAct.org](http://AskSigAct.org)
- [AskTheTable.com](http://AskTheTable.com)
- [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com)
- [basicallymoney.com](http://basicallymoney.com)
- [blogoverflow.com](http://blogoverflow.com)
- [chiphacker.com](http://chiphacker.com)
- [crossvalidated.com](http://crossvalidated.com)
- [CsTheory.org](http://CsTheory.org)
- [CycleQuery.com](http://CycleQuery.com)
- [Diablo3Acts.com](http://Diablo3Acts.com)
- [ElectionCheck.com](http://ElectionCheck.com)
- [ExpertUi.com](http://ExpertUi.com)
- [GameCouncil.com](http://GameCouncil.com)
- [GameCounsel.com](http://GameCounsel.com)
- [GetsThingsDone.net](http://GetsThingsDone.net)
- [hatdash.com](http://hatdash.com)
- [HatFight.com](http://HatFight.com)
- [IAskChicago.com](http://IAskChicago.com)
- [IAskNyc.com](http://IAskNyc.com)
- [IdleCoder.com](http://IdleCoder.com)
- [LieHound.com](http://LieHound.com)
- [MiniProfiler.com](http://MiniProfiler.com)
- [MiyOdEya.com](http://MiyOdEya.com)
- [MountainLionChallenge.com](http://MountainLionChallenge.com)
- [nothingtoinstall.com](http://nothingtoinstall.com)
- [RockStarHire.com](http://RockStarHire.com)
- [s.tk](http://s.tk)
- [seasonedadvice.com](http://seasonedadvice.com)
- [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com)
- [SexualityQa.com](http://SexualityQa.com)
- [SharePointOverflow.com](http://SharePointOverflow.com)
- [sstatic.net](http://sstatic.net)
- [stackapps.com](http://stackapps.com)
- [StackAthlon.com](http://StackAthlon.com)
- [stackauth.com](http://stackauth.com)
- [StackerNews.com](http://StackerNews.com)
- [StackEx.com](http://StackEx.com)
- [stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com)
- [StackOfdice.com](http://StackOfdice.com)
- [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com)
- [stackshowdown.com](http://stackshowdown.com)
- [superuser.com](http://superuser.com)
- [TheArQaDe.com](http://TheArQaDe.com)
- [TheGameCouncil.com](http://TheGameCouncil.com)
- [TheNewIpadIsHere.com](http://TheNewIpadIsHere.com)
- [TheNewNewNewIpad.com](http://TheNewNewNewIpad.com)
- [TruthCatcher.com](http://TruthCatcher.com)
- [Win8Challenge.com](http://Win8Challenge.com)
- [YoDeyA.com](http://YoDeyA.com)

Comment: How has the domain http://s.tk been registered? I thought the minimum length of a domain name (minus TLD) was two characters. Also, a whois search for s.tk returns me "Invalid output"

Comment: @caiosm1005 - That's up to each TLD's manager.  http://x.com is valid, for instance, but no new one-letter .coms are being created.

Comment: Surely Oded doesn't need the reputation, but [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/164054/timeline) still bothers me. Why repeating an earlier answer?

Comment: @Arjan I guess the aim here on meta, as elsewhere on StackExchange, is to create a single, best, definitive answer, which can then be accepted; and that can mean merging bits from other answers too. I think I've understood that right, but please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Sure, that's the aim. But there are things like attribution. You saw my answer and thought to use it - fine. Could have added something about that fact.

Comment: Like @Oded, I disagree here, but even think attribution was not good enough here. Changing a useless answer (your first revision was useless, I feel) into a good answer by copying someone else's answer (which also was older) smells VERY bad to me. You should just have deleted your answer, I feel.